# get normal transaction by transaction hash in etherscan api

Tags: api, etherscan

its giving details about the txhash on etherscan website but not giving output in api named("Get 'Internal Transactions' by Transaction Hash")

giving this result:

```
{"status":"0","message":"No transactions found","result":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=<tx_hash>&apikey=<YourApiKeyToken>`

This will output:

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":1,
   "result":{
      "blockHash":"0xf850331061196b8f2b67e1f43aaa9e69504c059d3d3fb9547b04f9ed4d141ab7",
      "blockNumber":"0xcf2420",
      "from":"0x00192fb10df37c9fb26829eb2cc623cd1bf599e8",
      "gas":"0x5208",
      "gasPrice":"0x19f017ef49",
      "maxFeePerGas":"0x1f6ea08600",
      "maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x3b9aca00",
      "hash":"0xbc78ab8a9e9a0bca7d0321a27b2c03addeae08ba81ea98b03cd3dd237eabed44",
      "input":"0x",
      "nonce":"0x33b79d",
      "to":"0xc67f4e626ee4d3f272c2fb31bad60761ab55ed9f",
      "transactionIndex":"0x5b",
      "value":"0x19755d4ce12c00",
      "type":"0x2",
      "accessList":[
         
      ],
      "chainId":"0x1",
      "v":"0x0",
      "r":"0xa681faea68ff81d191169010888bbbe90ec3eb903e31b0572cd34f13dae281b9",
      "s":"0x3f59b0fa5ce6cf38aff2cfeb68e7a503ceda2a72b4442c7e2844d63544383e3"
   }
}
```

documented in etherscan here: `https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/geth-parity-proxy`